# RaspberryPi 4b won't boot from SD card anymore

Tags: pi-4, boot, sd-card

I have used my RaspberryPi 4B multiple times with the same sd card. Everything worked perfectly fine. To test if the RaspberryPi fits in a case I got for it, I removed the sd card. After putting it back in the RasPi won`t boot anymore.
It detects the card but gives me this error:
Failed to open device: 'sdcard' (cmd 371a0010 status 1fff0001)

I found multiple threads with the same screen, but none of them seem to have a sdcard that used to work. If it worked before, is the sdcard broken? Or is it the reader? Can the data from the card be saved?

[image]

Comment: Have a close look at the SD card (magnifying glass if possible) and see if it is cracked.  I have done this before with a new case, either putting the pi in or taking it out with card in.

Comment: 1. try reading the SD card in another device. 2. try using a different SD card in the Pi - depending on which works and which doesn't you can determine if the fault is with the SD card or with the Pi itself

Comment: `is the sdcard broken? Or is it the reader? Can the data from the card be saved?` ... only you can answer these questions ... everybody else is only guessing ... perhaps you mean to ask something else